# SQL Server columnstore index update/insert in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-update, columnstore

I was having fun testing out the columnstore index feature of sql server 2012. Because you can't update/insert tables with such indices I read on some options: keep a separate table and use a new partition for every bulk insert or disable the index, perform updates/inserts and then rebuild the index.

For my test I chose the latter option and ended up with this stored procedure:

```
-- Disable the columnstore index.
ALTER INDEX [All_Columns_Columnstore_Index] ON [dbo].[Tick] DISABLE

-- Insert data into tick table from staging table.
insert into Tick
select [Date],
       SymbolID,
       Price
from TickTemporary

-- Delete data from staging table.
delete from TickTemporary

-- Enable (rebuild) the columnstore index.
ALTER INDEX [All_Columns_Columnstore_Index] ON [dbo].[Tick] REBUILD
```

If I execute these lines manually everything works fine. But if I run the procedure, I get the error that updates/inserts can't be performed on a table that has a columnstore index.

Why is this?

Update:

I followed the advice in the answer I previously accepted but I still get the same thing.

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Disable the columnstore index.
EXEC DisableColumnStoreIndex

-- Insert data into tick table from staging table.
insert into Tick
select [Date],
       SymbolID,
       Price
from TickTemporary

-- Delete data from staging table.
delete from TickTemporary

-- Enable (rebuild) the columnstore index.
EXEC RebuildColumnStoreIndex
```

Even tried placing "begin tran" and "commit tran" around the sproc calls.

Using dynamic sql like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql =
    'insert into Tick
     select [Date],
            SymbolID,
            Price
     from TickTemporary'
exec(@sql)
```

works, but really, I want to get by without dynamic sql. Isn't it possible in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check is done at compile time, not at execution time. Separate the procedure into it's own, or use dynamic SQL.

But as a general comment this is not the right approach. You should insert into a different table with identical structure, build the columnstore index on this identical table, then use partition switch to replace the old table with the new table: switch out the old table with an empty one, switch in the new table, drop the old data switched out. Similar to the procedure described in [How to Update a table with a Columnstore Index](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/how-to-update-a-table-with-a-columnstore-index/). Because of the use of partition switch the users of your table experience a much shorter downtime, as the old table is still online and available during the insert and during the build columnstore stages.

Comment: Yes. I plan to use that strategy in the future. But right now this is just a very small experiment of mine and I don't have that much data. But I have read the link you refer to so I know of that method. I just got stuck when this simple thing didn't work.

Comment: I don't think you understood the advice. Your attempt stiull has to compile a stored procedure that INSERTs into a columnstore index, and that will trigger the error. You must separate the INSERT as to not being compiled while the columnstore index exists, is simple as that and there is no workaround. Dynamic SQL is an example that forces the compile to occur at the right time.

Comment: Oh sorry. I get it then. Though I think it's weird that the same check isn't done when you actually execute the "CREATE PROCEDURE" or "ALTER PROCEDURE" statement. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution For This compile time execution  is   **Option(recompile)**

```
create  PROCEDURE TEST
AS
BEGIN

ALTER INDEX [All_Columns_Columnstore_Index] ON [dbo].[Tick] DISABLE

-- Insert data into tick table from staging table.

insert into Tick
select [Date],
       SymbolID,
       Price
from TickTemporary  **Option(recompile)**

-- Delete data from staging table.
delete from TickTemporary

-- Enable (rebuild) the columnstore index.
ALTER INDEX [All_Columns_Columnstore_Index] ON [dbo].[Tick] REBUILD

End
```