# Stored procedure not executing drop statement for Columnstored Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Columnstored Non-Clustered Index on TbName, I have this statement inside a stored procedure. When I execute the stored procedure seems like the control is not entering the Drop statement.

[SQL Server columnstore index update/insert in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117478/sql-server-columnstore-index-update-insert-in-stored-procedure). This link does explain the cause, but I'm looking for a work around.

Any help?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('TbName') AND NAME ='Index')
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX [Index] ON [TbName];
END
```

Adding Snippet of my SQL Script below

```
--Example Procedure
CREATE PROC DropIndexCheck
AS
BEGIN TRY

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('temp.FactMetric') AND NAME ='INXCU_FactMetric')
        BEGIN
            DROP INDEX [INXCU_FactMetric] ON [temp].[FactMetric];
        END

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('temp.FactMetric') AND NAME ='INXCU_FactMetric')
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_executesql N'DROP INDEX INXCU_FactMetric ON temp.FactMetric';
        END

    INSERT INTO [temp].[FactMetric]
        (
            [BuildVersionID]
          ,[EntityID]
          ,[MetricTypeID]
          ,[AdjustmentTypeID]
          ,[CurrencyID]
          ,[SecondaryClassID]
          ,[YOA]
          ,[MetricID]
          ,[BFWD]
          ,[CFWD]
          ,[Movement]

        )
    SELECT 
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

EXEC [qa].[uspRethrowError] @@PROCID;
END CATCH;


--Execute the Script Here
EXEC DropIndexCheck
```

I was able to do a get a workaround for this: (Not sure if this is the best way, but works)

Use the same Exists condtion before we call the stored procedure:

```
--Call the Drop Exists before calling the stored procedure
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('temp.FactMetric') AND NAME ='INXCU_FactMetric')
            BEGIN
                DROP INDEX [INXCU_FactMetric] ON [temp].[FactMetric];
            END

EXEC DropIndexCheck
```

In this case Index will be dropped before the execution of the stored procedure and the insert will not break.

Comment: Code does not belong in the title.  I moved it to the question.  Please fix the title.

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure works fine:

```
Create schema CS
Go
Create Table CS.CS_Table(col1 int, col2 int)
Go

Alter Proc CS.CS_proc_Drop
As 
Begin
    Declare @schema sysname = N'CS', @table sysname = N'CS_Table', @index sysname = N'CS_Table_Index'

    IF Exists(Select 1 From sys.indexes where OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = @table and OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) = @schema and name = @index)
    Begin
        Print 'drop'
        Drop Index [CS_Table_Index] on [CS].[CS_Table]
    End

    Insert Into [CS].[CS_Table](col1, col2) Select 1, 1

    IF Not Exists(Select 1 From sys.indexes where OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = @table and OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) = @schema and name = @index)
    Begin
        Print 'Create'
        Create nonclustered columnstore index [CS_Table_Index] on [CS].[CS_Table](col1)
    End
End
Go

exec CS.CS_proc_drop
select top 10 * from CS.CS_Table
Go
```

I made it work (fail...) and can reproduce it. The index must not be present at compile time when it checks the procedure. It works fine if:

- I drop the index manually after a create/alter
- The procedure is not being recompiled
- I don't execute DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
- The insert happens in a sub procedure or dynamic SQL

It fails as soon as it is being recompiled if the index is present.

You should call Proc2 from Proc1 right after the drop index and Proc2 will do the insert and index creation.
You can also run Proc1 first followed by Proc2.

In fact, this is similar to what is being said in the link you put in your quesiton.

Comment: Works for the first time then fails with the same error:
"INSERT statement failed because data cannot be updated in a table with a columnstore index"

Comment: Have you tried with mine first? Or with yours ? Are the object names in the if, delete and create identical? Does it print somthing out? I will update my query.